# Is OpenLayers compatible with OGC WKT SRS definitions?

Tags: openlayers-2, well-known-text

I'm trying to use WKT in OpenLayers.  Proj4js seems to have no problem with this but the OGC definition describes the units as "US survey foot" whereas OpenLayers has an INCHES_PER_UNIT definition of "us-ft".

Should this be addressed by registering "US survey foot":

```
OpenLayers.INCHES_PER_UNIT["US survey foot"] = OpenLayers.INCHES_PER_UNIT["us-ft"];
```

Or is there an openlayers/wkt incompatibility?

[This](http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/3421/ogcwkt/) is the wkt in question.  Normally I would use a WKID but this is a WKT test.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed `OpenLayers.INCHES_PER_UNIT["US survey foot"] = OpenLayers.INCHES_PER_UNIT["us-ft"];` was sufficient.  Odd OL doesn't pre-define this or WKT doesn't use "us-ft".